# Is there a specific term for such a chart?

Tags: data-visualization

Suppose I have a dataset comprising three binary variables that indicate whether or not an observation belongs to a certain group (X1 to X3) where

$X3 \subset X2 \subset X1 $. How is a graph that summarizes the data in a way like this called? 
[image]

I always considered this to be a Venn diagram but none of the Venn diagram packages in R or Stata would let me produce a graph like this. So is there maybe another word for this?

Comment: Venn diagram was the first term to come to my mind too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39063546/1457051 ; I tend to call them nested circle / nested euler  diagrams

Comment: @hrbrmstr That's perfectly fine for my purposes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: These are Euler circles. In your case, they are nested as @hrbrmstr. Asking for code is generally off topic here.

Comment: @MichaelChernick This particular graph cannot be a Venn diagram because a VD must be able to represent all possible intersections of the sets.

Comment: @giusti That is an extremely limited view of what Venn diagrams do.  One of their purposes is to be able to represent *precisely* such restricted relationships among sets.

Comment: @whuber I understand there's some room for ambiguity in my comment. What I meant to say is that this particular figure does not depict a Venn diagram.

Comment: @giusti It seems to *be* a Venn diagram: it depicts three sets and their relationships under set inclusion.

Comment: @whuber [That's an Euler diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Overview). "[A] Venn diagram for n component sets must contain all 2^n hypothetically possible zones that correspond to some combination of inclusion or exclusion in each of the component sets. Euler diagrams contain only the actually possible zones in a given context."

Comment: @giusti Thank you; I stand corrected and appreciate learning of the distinction.  Your interpretation agrees with Wikipedia, with Eric Weisstein, and others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, these kinds of diagrams are [Euler diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram), of which Venn diagrams are a subset. In fact, you could make a Euler diagram depicting this relationship.